How to Implement Bluetooth Classic POS Terminal Printing Using SPP and Protobuf in .NET Maui?
I'm working on a .NET MAUI application where I need to send a receipt to a POS terminal over Bluetooth. The POS terminal supports Bluetooth communication and expects messages to be in Protobuf format.
I’ve already written the basic Bluetooth communication code, which connects to the POS terminal using the following code:
var bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
var device = (from pd in bluetoothAdapter.BondedDevices where pd.Name == "Pos-terminal" select pd).Single();
using var socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))!;

socket.Connect();
// ReceiptsRequest Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.
var data = new ReceiptsRequest
{
   OrderNo = "1234",
   Receipts =
   {
       Receipt.CustomerReceipt
   }
};

var outputStream = socket.OutputStream!;
var bytes = data.ToByteArray();

outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
outputStream.Flush();

socket.Close();

However, the terminal expects the message to be in Protobuf format, such as:
syntax = "proto3";

package com.uaepay.pos.ecr.acquire;

message AcquireReceipt {
  common.Money amount = 1;
  optional string subject = 2;
  optional string paymentMethod = 3;
  optional string reserved = 4;
}

message ReceiptsRequest {
  string orderNo = 1;
  repeated Receipt receipts = 2;
}

The terminal’s service endpoint is /acquire/refund/receipts/print, and I need to send the Protobuf-encoded receipt data to this service.
What I Need Help With

Protobuf Serialization: How can I serialize my AcquireReceipt data into Protobuf format in .NET MAUI?

Bluetooth Communication: How can I send the serialized Protobuf data to the POS terminal over Bluetooth in the current code structure?
Printing the Receipt:

How can I trigger the receipt printing on the POS terminal after sending the message?


My Attempt
I’m not sure how to modify my existing code to handle Protobuf serialization and Bluetooth communication properly. Here’s how I think the process might work:

Use a Protobuf library like Google.Protobuf to serialize my AcquireReceipt.
Send the serialized data over the Bluetooth socket.
The terminal will automatically print the receipt once the correct message is sent.
Can anyone provide guidance or code snippets on how to implement Protobuf serialization, send it over Bluetooth in .NET MAUI, and print the receipt?


What kind of printer is this?  Most BT POS printers are pretty dumb, using protobuf seems pretty unusual

Receipt printers usually only work with ESC/POS or vendor-specific command system specifications. These are mostly unprocedural, mixed plain text and binary data. The only thing that probably specifies and requires protobuf messages is the POS terminal software. Check whether that software has an interface or method that simply sends data from outside and prints it to the printer, and if so, create the data accordingly and call it. If you are the author of the POS terminal software, please design and implement such a function in it.

The POS terminal supports Bluetooth communication and expects messages to be in Protobuf format: You may consider including Manufacturer and model number along with URLs to the documentation.
